# Redirect users to intended page after signin with Angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS with UI-Router and Meteor and want to redirect users to their intended destination after successfully logging in. I have a Meteor Session variable storing the intended page. After signing in, which I currently have implemented according to my previous [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782269/how-to-redirect-users-with-unverified-emails-using-angular-ui-router) reproduced below, how do I redirect the user to the intended login page?

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, UserService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
        // don't check auth on login routes
        if (toState.name === "signin") {
            if (UserService.doesNotHaveVerifiedEmail()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                Session.set("INTENDED_STATE_NAME", toState.name);
                $state.go('signin');
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share the whole project?